JSON Decode Exception
import requests
import json

URL = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/TESTGET_api/"


def get_data(id = None):
    data = {}
    if id is not None:
        data = {'id':id}
    json_data = json.dumps(data)
    r = requests.get(url= URL, data = json_data )
    data = r.json()
    print(data)        
get_data()

this is the code, the problem lies at r.json(). Please guide with the solution.
I tried using print(r.content) before data = r.json(). but still not working.

The issue might be with how you're sending the data to the server. When you use requests.get() with the data parameter, it sends the data as query parameters, not in the request body. For sending JSON data in the request body with a GET request, you can use the json parameter instead.

What is the result of requests.get(url= URL, data = json_data ).content?

you did not provide any indication of what the result of the operation was.  please provide that and as asked the content value returned.  check the status code of the result.  That might indicate an error servicing the request from the server providing the answer
